# iphone sdk Creating custom Templates

Tags: iphone, xcode, project-template

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/2075/screenshot20100628at101.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/2075/screenshot20100628at101.png) 
Cocos Provides a .sh file to install cocos2d templates.

My task is very much similar to that. 
I have to create One User Template Group.  Similar to screen shot.

My question is how ? How to create a group under "user templates" ?

Comment: [Here you go](http://www.iphonedevfaq.com/index.php?title=Xcode_project_templates)

Comment: [I found an another link](http://www.turkeysheartrhinos.com/?p=8#custom_project_templates).